# Why can't I print numbers in assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I have my code right but linux won't print the ascii character that I specify

I haven't tried much else because my code is right, and I followed a tutorial.

```
mov rcx, [digitSpacePos]
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, rcx
mov rdx, 1
syscall
```

It's supposed to print 123 because digitSpace is 123 but it's printing nothing.

Comment: It can't possibly print 123 because you specified 1 for length. Also, write expects a pointer to the thing to write and you need to convert to text if you want a number printed.

Comment: for an example have a look here: https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmtutorial/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
        global    _start

           section   .data
message:  db        "123", 10               ; note the newline at the end

         section   .text
_start:   mov       rax, 1                  ; system call for write
          mov       rdi, 1                  ; file handle 1 is stdout
          mov       rsi, message            ; address of string to output
          mov       rdx, 4                  ; number of bytes
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to do the write
          mov       rax, 60                 ; system call for exit
          xor       rdi, rdi                ; exit code 0
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to exit
```